# Selecting users with top hourly connections

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, max

I import IIS Logs into SQL Server.

The table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IIS_Log (
    [cdate] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [ctime] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [username] [VARCHAR] (16) NULL
    )
```

Each row in `IIS_Log` shows a connection between users and the server like this:

```
username | cdate      | ctime
---------+------------+------
Andy     | 2014-01-01 | 07:10
Andy     | 2014-01-01 | 07:13
Andy     | 2014-01-01 | 07:45
Andy     | 2014-01-01 | 07:05

Andy     | 2014-01-01 | 09:30
Andy     | 2014-01-01 | 09:13

Andy     | 2014-01-01 | 17:45

John     | 2014-01-01 | 12:05
John     | 2014-01-01 | 12:05
John     | 2014-01-01 | 12:05
John     | 2014-01-01 | 12:25
John     | 2014-01-01 | 12:32

John     | 2014-01-01 | 13:00   -- These connections should not
John     | 2014-01-01 | 13:09   -- come in the result set because a heavier
John     | 2014-01-01 | 13:15   -- connection exists for John (with 5 connections)
John     | 2014-01-01 | 13:18   --

John     | 2014-01-01 | 10:10
John     | 2014-01-01 | 10:12

John     | 2014-01-01 | 07:10

David    | 2014-01-01 | 05:20
```

I want to see **hourly total connections** of users that have at least 3.

Note that only one row per user is needed. In this example, John shouldn't come twice.

So the example's result set would be this:

```
username | connections | cdate      | ctime
---------+-------------+------------+------
Andy     | 4           | 2014-01-01 | 07
John     | 5           | 2014-01-01 | 12
```

Answer (score 3):

```
;with x as (
    select username, cdate, left(ctime,2) as hr, count(*) as cnt
    from iis_log
    group by username, cdate, left(ctime,2)
),
y as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by username, cdate order by cnt desc) as rn
    from x
)
select *
from y
where rn = 1
and cnt >= 3
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to do it without `partition by`, just as an academic exercise ?

Comment: Hello dean and thank you for your attention. But I wouldn't ever think of such an absolutely complicated query. It's very strange. Of course that might be because of my lack of knowledge in SQL Serevr `:-/`. Thank you again and +1.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is just like dean's. But I don't use `CTE`. I am also trying to do it without the `partition by` -

```
select *
from 
(
select 
ROW_NUMBER() over (
    partition by username order by username asc, 
    count(username) desc
) as rowid,
username, 
cdate, 
LEFT(ctime,2) as ctime, 
COUNT(username) as cnt
from IIS_Log
group by username, cdate, LEFT(ctime,2)
having COUNT(username) >= 3
) as src 
where rowid = 1
```

Comment: CTE is just a syntactic sugar over subquery, it only adds to readability, nothing else. But I don't understand -- you *do* partition by, don't you?

Comment: @dean - yes. actually, i was trying see how it can be done without row_number, partition by and over, just for fun.

Comment: Sure, it is doable, same as riding a bycicle from Paris to Moscow -- but I'd use the train nowadays :) Window functions are probably the most valuable addition to the T-SQL since 2005.

Comment: @dean - correct. I was just trying to see what life was like before 2005. I got some result, but it is not useful to the op - `select username,MAX(cnt) as maxx
from 
(
select 
username,
cdate, 
LEFT(ctime,2) as ctime, 
COUNT(username) as cnt
from IIS_Log
group by username, cdate, LEFT(ctime,2)
having COUNT(username) >= 3
) as src 
group by username`

Comment: Thank you very much. But `ROW_NUMBER() over partition by` is very strange for me! It's the first time ever I see that (I've newly come to SQL Server and I still know myself a PHP/MySQL lover, maybe that's why I cannot understand this non-SQL command of SQL Server). Would yu please post the bicycle base solution?!!! So that I can accept it.